# Parse YAML to key value and include yaml categories

Tags: ruby, yaml

Was looking to parse a YAML file into plain key=value strings.

I have some initial structure, but I wanted to get some of the keys from a yaml as well.

```
test:
   line1: "line 1 text"
   line2: "line 2 text"
   line3: "line 3 text"
options:
    item1: "item 1 text"
    item2: "item 2 text"
    item3: "item 3 text"
```

Ruby:

```
File.open("test.yml") do |f|  
  f.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp

    if line =~ /:/
        line.chop
        line.sub!('"', "")
        line.sub!(": ", "=")
        line.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
        printline = line.strip
        puts "#{printline}"
        target.write( "#{printline}")
    end
  end
end
```

The results currently look like

```
test:
line1=line 1 text
line2=line 2 text
line3=line 4 text
options:
item1=item 1 text
item2=item 2 text
item3=item 3 text
```

But I am looking to add the category before like:

```
test/line1=line 1 text
test/line2=line 2 text
test/line3=line 3 text
options/item1=item 1 text
options/item2=item 2 text
options/item3=item 3 text
```

What is the best way to include the category for each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the YAML#load_file, read each line and adapt it to your need:

```
foo = YAML.load_file('file.yaml').map do |key, value|
  value.map { |k, v| "#{key}/#{k}=#{v}" }
end
foo.each { |value| puts value }

# test/line1=line 1 text
# test/line2=line 2 text
# test/line3=line 3 text
# options/item1=item 1 text
# options/item2=item 2 text
# options/item3=item 3 text
```

Comment: This looks like the correct way of doing what I was trying to do, thanks.

Comment: What if there are multiple levels in the yaml?  Do I have to add another map?

Comment: How's it, can you exemplify?

Comment: I figured it out actually, I parse out the value by doing a value.map do |newkey, newvalue|  -  This way If I have a third nested yaml, it can break that down. Thanks again, helps a bunch. This mapping is new to me, I will have to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert YAML to a hash:

```
#test.yml
test:
   line1: "line 1 text"
   line2: "line 2 text"
   line3: "line 3 text"
options:
    item1: "item 1 text"
    item2: "item 2 text"
    item3: "item 3 text"


#ruby
hash = YAML.load File.read('test.yml')
```

Now you can do anything you want with the hash, get the keys, values etc.

```
hash['options']['item1'] #=> "item 1 text"
hash['test']['line1'] #=> "line 1 text"
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is expecting. The OP seems to want to do it by themselves.

Comment: The question asked how to get key values.  "do it by themselves"  means exactly what?

Comment: Thanks for your input, this could be helpful in the future.